# How to properly display an image

Tags: beamer

How to set an image into beamer in the center of page under which its caption's displayed, please?

Any brilliant suggestion, please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is "just as you'd do it in any other document class" brilliant?

You can enclose the image using the `figure` environment (don't worry, the image won't float away since `beamer` internally  suppresses the flotation for `figure` and `table`) and then use `\caption` to provide the caption (if *really* required):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{A test caption}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[orange]
  (-3,-3) rectangle (4,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A test caption}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what's the difference between tikz's package and includegraphics ?

Comment: @Djouma `\includegraphics` is a command (provided by the `graphicx` package which is internally loaded by `beamer`) for including image files. TikZ is a package for drawing.

Comment: @Djouma I added an example using a `tikzpicture` to my answer.

Comment: how to set an image heigher using graphics please ?

Comment: yshift maybe .?

Comment: @Djouma you can use `\vfill` right after `\end{figure}`.

Comment: @Djouma or use `\begin{frame}[T]...\end{frame}`.

Comment: Is it possible to resize the caption ?

Comment: @Djouma Sure. You can use something like `\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny}` in the preamble (instead of `\tiny` use the desired font switch).

Comment: Another question please : how to set minimize the space size between the caption and its relative image ?

Comment: @Djouma this (although related) demands some extra work, and comments are not siotable for code. Please, feel free to open a new fresh question.

Comment: @Djouma You can add to the preamble `\setlength\abovecaptionskip{1pt}` (the default value is `7pt`), so now the caption is `6pt` closer to the image; of course, you can use any other value according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you additionally want to remove the prefix `Figure:` from the caption text [which is in my personal opinion uninformative in beamer], than you could use something like the following code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\insertcaption}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{test}
        \end{figure}
    \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]